# Mail on macOS Catalina: Disable "Load remote content in messages"

Tags: mail.app, privacy

In previous versions of Mail on macOS, there was an entry in Settings that read "Load remote content in messages".

I'd like to disable loading remote content. Is that possible to do in Catalina, either via the GUI or via the command line?

Comment: The first place I’d look for would be the question marks in preferences etc, or mail help menu to find something related..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mail/cpmlprefview/13.0/mac/10.15

> Load remote content in messages
>   When remote content is retrieved from a server, information about your Mac can be revealed. You can deselect the option for increased security, but some messages may not display correctly.
>
> Remote content isn’t displayed in messages that Mail marks as junk.

This is found in

> ... the Mail app  on your Mac, choose Mail > Preferences, then click Viewing.

Comment: That setting does not appear to be there in macOS Catalina

Comment: the manual is of macOS Catalina. Could you post a screenshot? I am on Mojave.

Comment: https://jmp.sh/0kZp1iQ

Comment: it seems to be in 5th line from the top except the header, unless I misread something in your question. Do clarify if so.

Comment: :D thanks, I can't believe I somehow missed it